# How to parse EDIfact file containing multiple items using EDI.Net?

Tags: edi, edifact, edi.net

I am using [EDI.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net#model) from indice-co and i have a EDI file that contains multiple items, when i use the EdiGrammer.NewEdiFact and read the file using stream and deserialize it I get only 1 item from the file, the top most; how do i read the file using stream and deserialize it to a list?

***Code Example:***

```
 var editFactParser = EdiGrammar.NewEdiFact();




        var interchange = default(EdiModel.Interchange);
        using (
            var stream = File.Open("E:\\SomePath\\20191121020103.00000091.EDI", FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read))
        {
            interchange = new EdiSerializer().Deserialize<EdiModel.Interchange>(new StreamReader(stream),
                editFactParser );
        }
```

***EdiFact File Content***

```
UNA:+.? 'UNB+UNOA:2+DHLEUAPGW+CENTIRO+191030:1347+203516'UNH+240179+IFTSTA:D:01B:UN'BGM+77+9690108+9'DTM+9:201910301347:203'NAD+CZ+9690108'CNI+1+1032173'LOC+5+AMS::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PU+:::SHIPMENT PICKUP'RFF+CN:1297617'DTM+11:20191030:102'DTM+7:201910301329:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+10321732'UNT+15+240179'UNH+240180+IFTSTA:D:01B:UN'BGM+77+9690108+9'DTM+9:201910301347:203'NAD+CZ+96901083'CNI+1+2598018'LOC+5+ORY::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:116775116'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301336:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+2598018043'CNI+2+4911357323'LOC+5+CDG::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:1286700'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301339:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+49113573'CNI+3+4911401'LOC+5+CDG::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:129007'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301337:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+49114019'CNI+4+6194460'LOC+5+BRU::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:127214241'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301339:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+6194460856'CNI+5+7525715'LOC+5+ORY::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:ECONOCOM'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301336:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+75257154'CNI+6+752571'LOC+5+ORY::87'LOC+8+AMS::87'STS++PL+:::PROCESSED AT LOCATION'RFF+CN:ECONOCOM'DTM+11:20191029:102'DTM+7:201910301339:203'GID++1'PCI+18'GIN+BN+7525715'UNT+65+240180'UNZ+2+203516'
```

Comment: 1.- Can you share your POCO class? 2.- Can you specify which segment is the one that is multiple times, there are plenty in a EDI message, but for example the UNH can be only once, if that is the one that is multiple times the edi message might be wrong.

Comment: Hi have you managed to resolve this? This seems to be an issue with the segment terminators not being picked up correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the late reply, I was able to solve it, it was an issue how with how I was accessing the segments and what data I was trying to get back, after some more trial and error I was able to figure it out, I currently do not have access to the code and will try and post it back here when I get to it. Thank you.